# Javascript Dropdown List

Tags: php, javascript

I need to populate a drop down list from a Mysql table

my table will be like below

```
 Symbol    values

 G.n0000   10
 P.n0000   20
 W.n0000   40
 G.n0000   50
 P.n0000   60
```

I need to appear the Symbol values in the drop down box, but only the distinct values

eg: drop down list should show only G.n0000,P.n0000,W.n0000

What I have tried is below but it is not working

```
 <?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'offlinesurv') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

$result = $conn->query("select distinct symbol from tab");

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<select name='id'>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($id);
              $id = $row['symbol'];

              echo '<option value="'.$id.'"></option>';

}

echo "</select>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Comment: You are setting option values but option text is blank. Try echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$id.'</option>';

Answer (score 0):

EDIT
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

```
          unset($id);
          $id = $row['symbol'];
          $value = $row['value'];
          echo "<option value= '$value' >$id</option>";
```

}

Comment: I can't see $name. Do you mean option text?

Answer (score 0):

Values do not show in select options.

It's been a while since I did any PHP so I can't recall the syntax, but with straight html you need to put:

```
<option>Text You Want To See</option>
```

Value is an optional identifier for each option

So you could have

```
<option value='id'><Text you want to see</option>
```